# Implement a graph from adjacency list to Edge list using DFS C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

I have a text file that contains an adjacency list of undirected graph, 
example:
1 2 3
2 1 3 4
3 1 2 4
4 2 3
I am reading the file and storing it in an adjacency list,
I want to transfer this data to an Edge List,
I am trying to find out all Unique pair of edges,
Using the DFS I am getting the pairs but those are not unique,  
I am trying to eliminate the duplicate pairs ( a duplicate pair is <1,2> is same as <2,1>) but it is not happening.......
Here is the outut I am getting:
degree of 1 is : 2
Nember of vertices is :4
Numbe rof edges is : 5
Max degree is : 3
Min degree is : 2
List of edges : ..........

1 2
Edge 1 2 Inserted 
 Back : 2 1
Edge 2 1 Inserted

2 3
Edge 2 3 Inserted 
 Back : 3 1
Edge 3 1 Inserted 
 Back : 3 2
Edge 3 2 Inserted

3 4
Edge 3 4 Inserted 
 Back : 4 2
Edge 4 2 Inserted
 
 Back : 4 3
Edge 4 3 Inserted
 
 Back : 2 4
Edge 2 4 Inserted 
 Back : 1 3
Edge 1 3 Inserted

---

Thanks...
Sorry for the long code.........

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>  
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct EdgeList
{
    int u;
    int v;
}EdgeList;


class Graph
{
    public:
        vector<list<int> > adj;
        int V;
        int E;

        EdgeList *edges;

        Graph(int N):adj(N+1)
        {
            V = N;
        }
        Graph(int N, int M):adj(N+1)
        {
            V = N; 
            E = M; 
            int x = E+550;
            edges = new EdgeList[x];
        }

        void addEdgeList(Graph g, int u, int v);
        bool ischeckEdge(Graph g,int u,int v);

        void addEdge(int u, int v);
        void deleteSelfLoops(Graph g);

        int degree(Graph g, int v);
        int maxDegree(Graph g);
        int minDegree(Graph g);
        int edgeCount(Graph g);
        int numberOfSelfLoops(Graph g); 

        bool isEdge(Graph g, int u,int v);

        void DFS(Graph g);
        void dfsUtil(Graph g, int v, bool visited[] );              
};

int e = 0;
void Graph::addEdgeList(Graph g, int u, int v)
{
    if(ischeckEdge(g,u,v))
    {
        cout<<"Edge "<<u<<" "<<v<<" Inserted "<<endl;
        g.edges[e].u = u;
        g.edges[e].v = v;
        e++;
    }
}

bool Graph::ischeckEdge(Graph g, int u, int v)
{
    bool a,b,c,d;


    for(int i=0;i<=g.E; i++)
    {

        if( ((g.edges[i].u == u || g.edges[i].v == v) && (!g.edges[i].u == u || !g.edges[i].v == v)) )
        {
            cout<<"First block" ;
            return false;

        }
        else if( ((g.edges[i].u == v || g.edges[i].v == u) && (!g.edges[i].u == v || !g.edges[i].v == u)))
        {
            cout<<" sec block";
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}


void Graph::dfsUtil(Graph g, int v, bool visited[])
{
    list<int> temp;
    temp  = g.adj[v];

    if(!visited[v])
    {
         visited[v] = true; 
    }

    list<int>::iterator j;
    for(j = temp.begin();j != temp.end(); j++)
    {
        if(!visited[*j])
        {
            cout<<endl<<v<<" "<<*j<<endl;// print edges
            g.addEdgeList(g,v,*j);
            dfsUtil(g, *j, visited);
        }
        else //back edge
        {
            cout<<" Back : "<<v<<" "<<*j<<endl;
            g.addEdgeList(g,v,*j);
        }
    }   
}

void Graph::DFS(Graph g)
{
    bool *visited = new bool[g.V+1];
    int *parent = new int[g.V+1];

    for(int i = 0; i <= g.V; i++)
    {
         visited[i] = false;
         parent[i] = -1;
    }

    for(int v = 0; v <= g.V; v++)
    {
        if(!visited[v])
        {
            dfsUtil(g, v , visited);
        }
    }
 }

 bool Graph::isEdge(Graph g, int u, int v)
 {
     for(int w : adj[v])
     {
        if(u == w)
        {
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
 }


void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v); //undirected graph
    //adj[v].push_back(u);
}

void Graph::deleteSelfLoops(Graph g)
{
    for(int v = 0; v <= g.V; v++)
   {
        for(int w : g.adj[v])
        {
            if(v == w)
            {
                g,adj[v].remove(w);
            }
       }
    }
}

int Graph::degree(Graph g, int v)
{
     int deg = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i < g.adj[v].size();i++)
    {
        deg++;
    }   
    return deg;
}

int Graph::edgeCount(Graph g)
{
    int edge = 0;
    int i;

    if(g.adj[0].empty())
    {
         i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    for(i; i <= g.V; i++)
    {
        edge = edge + degree(g,i);
    }

   return edge/2; //handshaking lemma
}

int Graph::maxDegree(Graph g)
{
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= g.V; i++)
    {
        if(degree(g,i) > max)
        {
            max = degree(g,i);
        }
    }
    return max;
 }

int Graph::minDegree(Graph g)
{
    int min = g.V;
    int i;

    if(g.adj[0].empty())
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    for(i; i <= g.V; i++)
    {
        if(degree(g,i) < min)
        {
            min = degree(g,i);
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int Graph::numberOfSelfLoops(Graph g)
{
    int count = 0;

    for(int v = 0; v <= g.V; v++)
    {
        for(int w : g.adj[v])
        {
            if(v == w)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return count / 2;
 }



int main()
{
    ifstream fin("AdjList.txt");

    int V = 0;

    string str;

    while(getline(fin, str)) 
    {
    istringstream ss(str);
    int num;

    while(ss >> num)
    {
        // ... you now get a number ...
        int u;
        u = str[0] - '0'; //char can be coverted to int
        if(num != u )
        {
             //cout<<u<< "  "<< num<<endl;

        }
    }
    V++;
}
fin.close();

Graph g1(V);

fin.open("AdjList.txt");
while(getline(fin, str)) 
{
    istringstream ss(str);
    int num;

    while(ss >> num)
    {
        // ... you now get a number ...
        int u;
        u = str[0] - '0'; //char can be coverted to int
        if(num != u )
        {
             g1.addEdge(u,num);
             //cout<<u<< "  "<< num<<endl;

            }
        }
    }
    fin.close();

    Graph g(V,g1.edgeCount(g1));
    g.adj = g1.adj;

    cout<<"degree of 1 is : "<<g.degree(g,1)<<endl;
    cout<<"Nember of vertices is :"<<g.V<<endl;
    cout<<"Numbe rof edges is : "<< g.edgeCount(g)<<endl;
    cout<<"Max degree is : "<<g.maxDegree(g)<<endl;
    cout<<"Min degree is : "<<g.minDegree(g)<<endl;

    cout<<"List of edges : .........."<<endl;

    cout<< g.edges[4].u;

    for(int i=0; i<=g.E+500;i++)
    {
        g.edges[i].u=0;
        g.edges[i].v =0;
    }

    g.DFS(g); 


    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I did the debugging it seems that the problem is in ischeckEdge function, but cant figure it out what the problem is, may be I am not diong the checking in right and logical way, that is the reason I posted it......

Comment: Learn how to use your debugger efficiently. What are the variable values at the place to spot on?

Comment: The comma in g,adj[v].remove(w); should be a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I was thinking the problem was in ischeckEdge. it was comparing (0,0) as edges as in the input there is no vertex '0',

```
bool Graph::ischeckEdge(Graph g, int u, int v)
{
    bool a = false;

    swap(u,v);

    for(int i=0;i<=e; i++)
    {

        if(i == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(i ==1 && g.edges[i].u ==0 && g.edges[i].v ==0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(g.edges[i].u == u && g.edges[i].v ==v )
        {
            //cout<<"Same Edge"<<endl;
            a= false;
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            //cout<<"Edge count : "<<e<<endl;
            //cout<<"Iteration : "<<i<<endl;
            //cout<<"edge u v : "<<g.edges[i].u<<" "<<g.edges[i].v<<endl;
            //cout<<"input u v : "<<u<<" "<<v<<endl;
            a= true;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you index vertices with integers, the simple trick you can do is to add edge `{v, u}` if and only if `v <= u` (if there are no self-loops then `v < u` is sufficient). In order to do that, just change:

```
if(!visited[*j])
{
    cout<<endl<<v<<" "<<*j<<endl;// print edges
    g.addEdgeList(g,v,*j);
    dfsUtil(g, *j, visited);
}
```

to

```
if(!visited[*j])
{
    cout<<endl<<v<<" "<<*j<<endl;// print edges
    if(v <= *j)
    {
        g.addEdgeList(g,v,*j);
    }
    dfsUtil(g, *j, visited);
}
```